# Using `hana::is_valid` fails with const references

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, boost-hana

I am using hana to determine if an object has a `Length` member like so:

```
using boost::hana::is_valid;


static const auto has_length
    = is_valid([](const auto& obj)
            -> decltype(obj.Length(),void()) {});
```

This works fine....I can do static asserts with it all day to my hearts content.  So the next step is logically to `enable_if` a function:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T t) -> std::enable_if_t<has_length(t), void>
{
}
struct mine
{
    int Length() const { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    foo(mine{});
}
```

This works just fine....but as soon as I change the `T` to `const T&`, we get errors that there is no suitable overload: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/85Fz4z)

So my question is: why does this happen?

Comment: Best to include the error messages in your question.

Comment: Workaround for clang: `std::enable_if_t<has_length(T{}), void>`. However, GCC complains either way.

Comment: @ildjarn I completely forgot about that.....

Comment: @ildjarn: If you add both `constexpr mine()` and `constexpr mine(const mine&)` then [it works](https://godbolt.org/g/BZk4LL).

Comment: @Julius : I know, that was kind of my point – presumably one would _want_ this to work with non-literal types. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: My comment was not clear enough, sorry: It is not about the `constexpr`. If you add a copy constructor, then you should also add a default constructor. Then [clang compiles the example with `auto foo(T)`](https://godbolt.org/g/G5x1Kx).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that calling a function with a reference that is not constexpr is not constexpr. This is where [`hana::is_valid`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#a2d2e7e08e284f7e0bd1bd9c3ad0e0a2b) is useful because it returns an `integral_constant`-like value that contains a static constexpr boolean so we can just look at the return type. See [`bool_`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1integral__constant.html#adeaf00ee03ae0daf97d60d5258bd3703).

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

static auto has_length = hana::is_valid([](auto&& t)
  -> decltype(t.Length()) { });

template <typename T>
auto foo(T const& t)
  -> std::enable_if_t<decltype(has_length(t)){}, void>
                   // ^-- notice the return type 
                   // is a boolean integral constant
{ }

struct mine
{
  int Length() const { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
  foo(mine{});
}
```